# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject one of the object may have two types

Tags: c#, json

I have the following issue:

When I try to deserialize json I receive an exception because one of the property may have different type. As per the following example:

{
    "requestFieldValues ": [{
        "fieldId": "description",
        "label": "Description",
        "value": "Some string here"
    }, {
        "fieldId": "customfield",
        "label": "Change",
        "value": {
            "self": "https://some-url.com",
            "value": "Normal",
            "id": "1111"
        }
    }]
}

Is there a way to deserialize "value" to different data type then just "object"?

EDIT
I'm using Newtonsoft.Json:

```
output = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Request>(myjson)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO - please post your c# code also

Comment: Your JSON isn't valid.